# Android exploit demos to scare my parents?

Tags: android, user-education

I recently discovered that my parents' android phones have not received security updates for years because the phones are out of support. When I talked to them I realized that the benefit of up-to-date software is very abstract to them and that they clearly felt like I was overreacting.

I personally really understood the importance of software updates by watching exploit demos at IT conferences. So now I am wondering: Are there such demos aimed at educating everyday users?

I am thinking of something like https://haveibeenpwned.com/ or https://amiunique.org/ but for android.

Comment: As far as I know, Android phones normally update automatically. If theirs don't, they're probably too old to update. If they're too old, what do you want them to do, throw them away and buy new ones?

Comment: The fact that these are out-of-support devices is a very different scenario than just "updates". You don't want them to "understand the importance of updates" - you want them to spend a lot of money to get new phones. That's a very different ask ... I have edited your question to reflect this new information.

Comment: Maybe you could buy a new phone yourself and give your old one (which still has support, I hope) to your parents. This is how my wife does it and it works great!

Comment: Please don't do that to your parents. What they are doing (for you), is far harder as you would think. They love you, don't frighten them. (Btw, if you "inspire" them to buy new phones, they will do it from the money what they would spend for you.)

Comment: If you want to be a really hardcore mobil hacker guy, then root their phone and install a firmware for them with a newer Android. However, the likely result will be that you can't root the phone, or you will brick the phone. The best result is that you will have a very slow phone.

Answer (score 5):

Exploiting vulnerabilities in someone's personal device in order to educate is often a recipe for disaster.

If you show a video of someone else exploiting someone else's device, that's still going to be abstract and difficult to personalise.

It's better to create a parallel to something that they do understand and care about

- changing the oil filter on the car
- emptying the lint trap
- vaccinations
- dental cleaning
- replacing weather stripping
- etc.

Something that they know that they have to do on a schedule to maintain something they care about, and if they do not do it, damage occurs.

Digital technology is invisible, intangible, complex, and difficult to understand. Tie it to something that is visible, tangible, simple, and understandable.

Comment: If he uses his own device for the demo, what's wrong with that?

Comment: @MobutuSeseSekoKukuNgbendu because it would seem that the OP already has an up-to-date device ...

Comment: You've a point, but let's think of a simple scenario where he downloads a browser (from the app store) with vulnerable WebKit version. He may exploit it under 10 minutes, just by browsing the webpage hosted on his local network.

Comment: @MobutuSeseSekoKukuNgbendu "that's still going to be abstract and difficult to personalise"

Comment: You're right, but personalizing by "I've an out-dated software and I just visited this page, which was enough to compromise my device"?

Comment: Are you sure that a browser from the app store can have a vulnerability that compromises ***the device*** when the device is up-to-date?

Comment: There is a good video about it from the Youtuber named "LiveOverflow".
He did that, but I cannot find the specific video, since he made a lot of resource on WebKit exploitation.